# Installing Poppler on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, installation, package, poppler

I just downloaded Poppler 0.16.5 and I am clueless on how to install this package on cygwin. Can anyone tell me whats the proper command in order to install poppler?

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a poppler package inside Cygwin 1.7.17-1.

Run `setup.exe` and then do the following:

1. On the window titled "Cygwin Setup", click `Next>`
2. On the window titled "Cygwin Setup - Choose Installation Type" choose "Install from Internet" and click `Next>`
3. On the window titled "Cygwin Setup - Choose Installation Directory" leave the root directory as `C:\cygwin` and "Install for ALL USERS (recommended)" and then click `Next>`
4. On the window titled "Cygwin Setup - Select Local Package Directory" leave the defaults and click `Next>`
5. On the window titled "Cygwin Setup - Select Connection Type" leave the defaults (which is Direct Internet Connection) and click `Next>`
6. On the window titled "Cygwin Setup - Choose Download Site(s)" choose the mirror near your location and click `Next>`
7. On the window titled "Cygwin Setup - Select Packages" go to the "Text" section of packages and expand it. (Search for packages starting with "LibPoppler" and "Poppler")

Then, just click `Next>` and wait for the download and installation process.

Answer (score 0):

(Poppler was [added as a cygwin package](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-03/msg00085.html) about a year after I wrote this answer. Now it installs like any other package.)

---

Poppler isn't a cygwin package. There is no "command" to install it. You have to unpack and build it yourself.  (Poppler has *two* files you need to download.)

The download is a .tar.gz file. Unzip it, untar it, and change to its directory.

```
$ gunzip filename
$ tar -xvf filename
$ cd poppler-0.16.5
```

Now look for files named anything like "README" and "INSTALL". Read them and follow their instructions.

If you're missing something, download it from Cygwin, and install it that way. Things you might need if you haven't built a program from source before include

- gcc
- autoconf
- make